# htaccess replace the parameter in the url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL like this :
`https://example.com/coins/1&order_by=today` and several categories such as:

```
https://example.com/coins/1&order_by=new
https://example.com/coins/1&order_by=trending
```

You can also change the page so it will be 2 instead of 1 etc.. like : `https://example.com/coins/2&order_by=today`

I would like to change these to have https://example.com/today?page=1 etc instead of this above

I have read many responses on this subject and I searched the web, but unfortunately no solution works.
I tried this but it does not works:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?order_by=new(&.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?new/%1/%2 [L]
```

Comment: Please do add your tried htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?order_by=new(&.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?new%1/%2 [L]

Comment: Pointless to try and match on the query string here - because your URLs _don’t have any_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following htaccess Rules, please make sure to place these Rules at top of your htaccess file. Make sure to place your htaccess file inside root folder along with coins folder(not inside coins folder).

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/coins/(\d+)&order_by=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^  /%2?page=%1 [R=301,L]
```